# Encrypted version control

Tags: git, version-control

I'm looking for a remote version control system, and was looking at github. They clearly state that they do not store the data encrypted, but instead focus on server security.

Fair enough, but I'd like my stored data encrypted as its the basis of my entire business.

Are there other git hosting providers that you can recommend, that store data encrypted?

Or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: Have you considered using another version control instead of Git?

Comment: Yes, do you know any that stores data encrypted?

Comment: You can check out SourceAnywhere. It provides the database encryption feature. The hosted edition is also available. http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/version-control-source-control-sourceanywhere.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"gitcrypt" is one option for saving encrypted data on github (and dropbox, etc):

- https://gist.github.com/873637
- https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt

There is controversy about client-side encryption:

- http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/113221
- https://github.com/MrZYX/old_diaspora_wiki/blob/master/Why-client-side-encryption-is-a-bad-idea.md

Comment: I'm not sure that the arguments made with regard to web-based social networks (Diaspora) really apply here.  You may be the sole user of your encrypted repo, and certainly you're not trying to get mass global adoption of your encrypted git repo.

Comment: Links 3 and 4 are broken.