# Encryption and code archive files

Tags: security, encryption, cvs

We have this computer code which requires anyone who has access to it pay a license fee. We will pay the fee for our developers but they want our sysadmins to be licensed too as they can see the code archives. But if the code is stored encrypted in the archives then the sysadmins can see the files but not see the contents.
So does any software version control system allow encryption so that only the persons who are checking out the code will require the key and so be able to see the files decrypted.
I was thinking it wouldn't be hard to add this to pserver and cvs but if it is already done elsewhere why reinvent the wheel.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: mike, I'm lost.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set up a source control system that can perform server-side diffs in a way that would prevent a sysadmin from at least theoretically accessing the contents.  (i.e.: The source control system would not be able to store the decryption key in a place that the sysadmin couldn't access.)  Unless your sysadmins habitually browse the source control database contents, such a system should have no practical difference from an unencrypted system from the perspective of your vendor.

The only way to make the source control database illegible to a server admin is to encrypt files on the client before submitting them to the server.  For this to meet the desired goal, the decryption keys would need to be inaccessible to the admins, which is unlikely to be practical in most organizations since server admins typically have admin access on all client machines as well.  Ignoring this picky detail, it would also mean that all your source control system would ever see is encrypted binaries, which means no server-side diff or blame.  It also means potentially horrible bloat of your database size since every file will require complete replacement on each commit.  Are you really willing to sacrifice useability of your source control system in order to save licensing fees and/or placate this vendor?

Comment: "For this to meet the desired goal, the decryption keys would need to be inaccessible to the admins," -- This isn't quite correct. The desired goal is to eliminate unneeded licensing fees. To achieve that, you do not necessarily have to make the data absolutely inaccessible to admins. You have to make it acceptably inaccessible, and a violation of policy and employment agreements to do so. If I rent a car and part of the agreement says "no one else may drive this car," that does not mean that I must absolutely guarantee that no joyrider can  steal it. I need to take appropriate precautions.

Comment: @RobNapier: Instructing admins not to look at the data should be adequate in that case.  Given the vendor insistence on the licensing, it presumably isn't.  (Which, BTW, I don't happen to this is reasonable in any way.)

Comment: In many cases one must show a good faith effort to enforce your rules; just having rules is far from enough. This is a common situation in eDiscovery and other legal affairs which I have dealt with many times. Similarly when one owns a pool, one is liable for children falling into it if you don't build a fence. The fact that children can dig under a fence is not highly relevant, but the fence is. http://blogs.findlaw.com/injured/2012/06/is-your-swimming-pool-an-attractive-nuisance.html. I am not recommending SO as a place for legal or compliance advice.

Comment: In this case, there's already an impediment in place to looking at the content of the files (whether on disk or in the source control db): one must actually open a file to see its contents.  If casual observation of contents were possible, adding an additional impediment would make sense.  However, since it would at least appear not to be the case, I see little benefit in encryption via an admin-accessible key.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to give all your developers some secret key that they plug into the encryption/decryption routines of git's smudge and clean filters. And you want an encryption scheme that is capable of performing deltas.

First, see [Encrypted version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972219/encrypted-version-control) for some examples in git. As written, this can dramatically increase disk usage. However, there are ways to make more "diff-friendly" encryption at the cost of some security. See [diph](https://github.com/bjornedstrom/diph) for an example of how you might attack that. Also, any system that uses AES-ECB mode would diff quite well. (You generally shouldn't use AES-ECB mode because of its security flaws... one of those security flaws is that it can diff quite well... hey, that's what you wanted, so this seems a reasonable exception.)